# Lambda: Node: S3 Upload - Works Intermittently

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using the code below to write a log file to AWS S3 using AWS Lambda. It works sometimes but not others (50% success rate) and I can't understand why. Can anybody help?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3()

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    let key = 'log.' + Date.now() + '.txt'
    let data = 'How are you?'

    put_object('test', key, data).then((e) => { console.log(e) })
}

let put_object = async (bucket, file, data) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const params = {
            Body: data,
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: file,
            ACL: "public-read",
            ContentType: "text/html"
        }

        s3.putObject(params, (err, results) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

**Edit**....................

Thanks to @steadweb this function is totally reliable.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3()

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    let key = 'log.' + Date.now() + '.txt'
    let data = 'How are you?'

    await put_object('test', key, data).then((e) => { console.log(e) })
}

let put_object = async (bucket, file, data) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const params = {
            Body: data,
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: file,
            ACL: "public-read",
            ContentType: "text/html"
        }

        s3.putObject(params, (err, results) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Your `put_object()` function could simply `return s3.putObject(params).promise()`. There is no need to manually promisify the AWS SDK calls.

Comment: What do your CloudWatch Logs show? Is the Lambda function timing out in the failed cases, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your lambda is stopping *before* your async call has completed.

You'll need to `await` your call to `put_object` in order for it to complete successfully. As below

```js
await put_object('test', key, data);
```